# Question about complex integral on triangular path

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

Im supposed to prove that
$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dw}{w^4-1}=\frac{\pi(i-1)}{2}$$
along a triangular path with vertexes at
$-1+i$, $2-i$, $2i$

Define this enclosed area as $\gamma$.

Since $w^4-1=0\iff w^4=1 \iff w=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{4} k}$
So this enclosed area has $2$ non-continuos points at 
$e^{i0}=1,e^{i\frac{\pi}{2}}=i$

So by Cauchy's integral theorem
$$\int_\gamma f(w)dw=\int_{\gamma_1}f(w)dw+\int_{\gamma_2}f(w)dw$$
iff $\gamma_1 $ and $ \gamma_2$ are **inside** the curve $\gamma$, they don't have common points and going counterclockwise.

So the point is that we can choose simplyer paths to compute the integral.

Problem is how to find these paths. Since closed route is not dependent of the path, could we use circles with very small radius, say $\epsilon$? Centered at the non-analytic point. Is the circles usually the best route? Any other tips solving this / other same sort integrals will be appreciated.

Thanks for advice.

Answer (score 4):

Note that  $\frac{1}{w^4 - 1} = \frac12\frac{1}{w^2-1} - \frac 12 \frac{1}{w^2 + 1}$.

Now note that each of the summands has only one bad point in the interior of $\gamma$. So we can choose $f(w) = \frac{1}{w+1}$ and $g(w) = \frac{1}{w+i}$. So then by using the Cauchy Integral Formula we have:

$$\int_{\gamma}\frac{dw}{w^4-1} = \frac12 \int_{\gamma}\frac{dw}{w^2-1} - \frac 12 \int_{\gamma}\frac{dw}{w^2+1} = \frac 12 \int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{w-1}dw - \frac 12 \int_{\gamma} \frac{g(w)}{w-i}dw = 2\pi i\left(\frac 12 f(1) - \frac 12 g(i)\right) = \pi i \left(\frac 12 - \frac{1}{2i}\right) = \frac{\pi i (1 + i)}{2} = \frac{\pi(i - 1)}{2}$$